# How to handle Namespace collisions when using TreeView in UWP apps

Tags: treeview, uwp-xaml

An exception is thrown when setting "ItemContainerStyle" to "StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle" which is defined in generic.xaml. The message indicates the style is using "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeViewItem" rather than "Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeViewItem".

I removed ItemContainerStyle assignment to confirm that it is the line causing the exception.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="muxcontrols:TreeView">
                        <muxcontrols:TreeViewList x:Name="ListControl"
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItemDataTemplate}"
                                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}">
```

The problem seems obvious, but a proper solution evades me. To leverage the style, do I start prepending "muxcontrols:" in the generic.xaml file? This seems like a bad idea. Do I need to recreate the style and behaviors separately?

Comment: Please describe your question clearly. What were you doing? With my testing, if I just create a blank UWP project, I could directly use `TreeView` control on XAML page, I do not need to add 'muxcontrols' prefix.

Comment: When I create a blank UWP project, TreeView is not among the controls in the toolbox. That's why I installed the Microsoft.UI.Xaml package which I believe cause the conflicts.

Comment: What’s your project’s target version? And if you directly input ‘<TreeView/>’ on xaml page, did it work for you?

Comment: I tried (min build 17763 and target build 17134) to eliminate version problems, but it seems I need 17763 for both. Even though, I am not setting ItemsSource. I'm trying the technique used in the docs: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view" for the Music Library TreeView sample. My real project's min version is 16299.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried (min build 17763 and target build 17134) to eliminate version problems, but it seems I need 17763 for both. Even though, I am not setting ItemsSource. I'm trying the technique used in the docs: "learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/…" for the Music Library TreeView sample. My real project's min version is 16299.

So, the issue was clear. The [TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-build-17134) control is introduced from build 17134. If you're using the platform APIs, you need to make sure that your project's target version is 17134 or higher. Since you said you want to set ItemsSource. `ItemsSource` and its related APIs require Windows 10, version 1809 ([SDK 17763](https://developer.microsoft.com/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)) or later, so you need to make your project's target version is 17763.

Then, you could directly use the TreeView control like the following:

```
<TreeView></TreeView>
```

If you're using [Windows UI Library APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/#features), you need to follow the [Getting started with the Windows UI Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/getting-started)
 document to download and install the Windows UI Library. Please note:

> Important: To use WinUI 2.1, your project’s Min version must be 14393 or higher and the Target version must be 17763 or higher.

Then, if you want to use the TreeView control in WinUI library, in your XAML page, add a reference at the top of your page

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
```

On the XAML page, you could directly input the following:

```
<controls:TreeView></controls:TreeView>
```

Comment: Let me start by thanking you for your help and appologizing for lettng this thread to get off track.
I am not using Itemsource, and because my app has a min version of 16299, I am using the TreeView control in WinUI library. My question relates to my lack of understanding of what the ItemContainerStyle property is being set to since it appears the one located in generic.xaml is hardcoded to the TreeView in Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.

The easy answer is not to set the ItemContainerStyle property which eliminates the exception. As far as I can tell, it looks and behaves correctly.